# ReactJS - TypeError: this.state.cakes.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting an “TypeError: this.state.cakes.map is not a function”.

When I try log the `res.data`

```
{data: Array(3), status: "Success", message: null}
```

Please, help to find what is the problem.

Here is the code.

```
 class ListCake extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                cakes : []
            }
        }
    
        componentDidMount(){
            CakeService.getCakes().then((res) => {
                try {
                     this.setState({ cakes : res.data });
                } catch(error){
                     console.log(error);
                }          
            });
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {
                      <div className='card card1'>
                          {
                              this.state.cakes.map(
                                  cake => 
                                  <React.Fragment>
                                  <div className="price"><h6>{ cake.price }</h6></div>
                                  <div className='info'>
                                  <h1 className='title'>{ cake.name }</h1>
                                  <p className='description'>{ cake.description }</p>
                                </div>
                                </React.Fragment>
                              )
                          }
                      </div>
                    }          
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
export default ListCake;
```

When I try log the error :

```
TypeError: this.state.cakes.map is not a function
    at ListCake.render (ListCake.jsx:42)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17485)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17435)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19073)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21893)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:12467)
    at ListCake.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:365)
    at ListCake.jsx:15
```

Comment: try res.data.data instead of res.data.

Comment: Probably trying to do array method on a js object

Comment: @IleshPatel it's ok but I don't understanding. Can you explain for me.

Comment: I think I've already seen this question earlier today; next time, please update the original question with the additional information rather than posting a new one and delete the old one (I assume, as I cannot find it anymore with the search function).

Comment: @namkellbi when you do console.log(res.data), it shows {data: Array(3), status: "Success", message: null}, now you want to access array within json, and for that you need res.data.data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the type error is that you are setting a whole response in your state and calling the map function on a cakes object which is wrong. If you want to store all the response on your state then access your array like this: this.state.cakes.data.map else you can just set your state like this: this.setState({cakes: res.data.data}); and access the map function directly.

```
/// Wrong
componentDidMount(){
   CakeService.getCakes().then((res) => {
      try {
        this.setState({ cakes : res.data }); // Here is your Mistake: res.data please replace res.data with res.data.data
       } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
      }          
    });
}


/// Correct
componentDidMount(){
   CakeService.getCakes().then((res) => {
      try {
        this.setState({ cakes : res.data.data });
       } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
      }          
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually saw your mistake, try this:

In the render method, you used res.state.cakes.map(),
but map function is valid for Arrays and not Objects.

But you have a data key pointing to an Array with 3 items, so simply do this:

```
{
                             this.state.cakes.data.map(
                                  cake => 
                                  <React.Fragment>
                                  <div className="price"><h6>{ cake.price }</h6></div>
                                  <div className='info'>
                                  <h1 className='title'>{ cake.name }</h1>
                                  <p className='description'>{ cake.description }</p>
                                </div>
                                </React.Fragment>
                              )
                          }
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be res.data.data

```
this.setState({ cakes : res.data.data });
```

and also map state like that

```
                     this.state.cakes?.map(
                                  cake => 
                                  <React.Fragment>
                                  <div className="price"><h6>{ cake.price }</h6></div>
                                  <div className='info'>
                                  <h1 className='title'>{ cake.name }</h1>
                                  <p className='description'>{ cake.description }</p>
                                </div>
                                </React.Fragment>
                              )
```

with question mark because it might be undefined.